# Replacement of date with ...ago java

Tags: jodatime

I have started building a logic in java that will take date input in 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' format and display output in following manner:

if the date is of today/yesterday then it should be :today/yesterday HH:mm am/pm
if it is less than 7days ago : x days ago
if it is more than 7 days ago : last week
similarly
two weeks ago
three weeks ago
a month ago(i.e.four weeks ago)
2 months ago
..
11 months ago
a year ago
and then x years ago.
All I need is proper calculation of days from todays date.
I came across joda-time to make my work easy but I am not able to find out if it has any inbuilt stuff that will give me desired output.

`int days = Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(), new LocalDate()).getDays();`

I wrote this code for today to today but I don't know how to go about rest in joda-time.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my logic.Thanks anyways!
`String convertDateToWords(String datestr) throws java.text.ParseException{

```
//here datestr is in this format from mysql database: "2015-03-03 09:14:04.0";

SimpleDateFormat formatter =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date bDate = formatter.parse(datestr);

Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTime(bDate);

String str = "";
String ampm = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(bDate);
int fromYear = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int toYear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

int fromMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int toMonth = date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

date.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
int fromDay = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int toDay = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

if(fromYear!=toYear){
    str = (fromYear-toYear)+" year(s) ago";
}else if(fromMonth!=toMonth){
    str = (fromMonth-toMonth)+" month(s) ago";
}else{
    int diff = fromDay - toDay;        
    if(diff == 0){
        str = " today | "+ampm;
    }
     if(diff == 1){
        str = " yesterday | "+ampm;
    }
     if(diff >=2 && diff <7){
        str = " "+diff+" days ago";
        str = getDay(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))+" | "+ampm;
    }
    if(diff >=7 && diff <14){
        str = " last week";
    }
    if(diff >=14 && diff <21){
        str = " 2 weeks ago";
    }
    if(diff >=21 && diff <28){
        str = " 3 weeks ago";
    }
    if(diff >=28){
        str = " 4 weeks ago";
    }
}

return str;
}
```

Comment: I have already accepted,its just that I developed and deployed my logic before you posted your answer.